# Dirac delta - $\delta(t-S)$ - impulse function at multiple occasions S

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dirac-delta

Apologies in advance, my mathematics is likely to be very ad hoc, but I hope it makes sense...

I have a software package that models data using multivariate stochastic differential equations, however the following non-stochastic differential is all that is necessary for my query:

$$dy(t) = Ay(t)dt+x(t)\delta(t-S)dt$$

Based on observations $1,2,3,...,n$ of vectors $y(t)$ and $x(t)$, which were made at times $s \in S$.

I am concerned about the Dirac delta here - this is the best representation I have been able to come up with for what the model is doing, in that the impact of $x(t)$ on $y(t)$ is an instantaneous impulse of magnitude $x(t)$ whenever $t \in S$.

The solution of this with values known at $t_{0}$, $t_0 >= 0$, $t > t_0$, and all $S >= t_0$, should then be:

$$y(t) = e^{A(t-t_0)}y(t_0) + \sum_{s= \min (S \in [t_0,t])}^{max(S \in [t_0,t])} e^{A(t-s)} x_s $$

So, first I would ask: Is my representation appropriate and correct?

Then: Is there a better / more parsimonious way to convey such a model / phenomenon?

Comment: Your representation is fine. A more terse description uses Heaviside step functions instead, but it's the same. As you say, the point is that you have the exponential behavior until the first jump, say it's at $s_1$; then you can treat that as a new IVP, whose initial condition is $y(s_1)+x(s_1)$. Then that obeys exponential behavior until $s_2$, etc. Alternately you can treat this in frequency space using the Laplace transform.

Comment: Thanks very much. I just included some missing dt's in the first equation - I assume this doesn't change your response?

Comment: Nah, I knew what you meant.